# TSQL how do you iterate through rows while parsing them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parsing

Sorry for the poor question wording I wasn't sure how to describe this. I want to iterate through every row in a table and while doing so, extract a column, parse the varchar that is in it and depending on what it finds insert rows into another table. Something along the lines of this:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max);
foreach row in (select * from Table) {
    set @string = row[column];
    while (len(@string) > 0) {
        -- Do all the parsing in here

        if (found what was looking for)
            insert into Table2 values(row[column2], row[column3]);
    }
}
```

It would be really nice for this to be a stored procedure so for it to be done in SQL. I'm just not too sure on how to approach it. Thanks.

Edit:

This is basically the functionality I was hoping for:

```
Table 1   |
id_number | text    |
1           Hello, test 532. Yay oh and test 111   
2           test 932.
3           This is a test 315 of stuff test 555.
4           haflksdhfal test 311 sadjhfalsd
5           Yay.
```

I want to go through this table and parse all of the text columns to look for instances of 'test #' where # is a number. When it finds something inside of the text in that format it will insert that value into another table like:

```
Table 2   |
id_number | number
1           532
1           111
2           932
3           315
3           555
4           311
```

Comment: +1: Thx for the update - I could see a regex being really helpful, but SQL Server doesn't have native regex support (PATINDEX has limited support).  To get regex support, SQL Server 2005+ requires you to use CLR functions/procedures.  Pulling out multiple values from a single row won't be pretty, but using a cursor would be painful - you'll have to know the row you're on, and in the case of rows 1 and 3 - where you left off.

Comment: Are the numbers are 3 digits?

Comment: @OMG Ponies - No they can be arbitrary digits, and they don't even have to be in that format, they could be
test - 5162
test 350
test as392
I want to go through and try and if I find test, to then try and extract a number near by so if there were mistypes it's smart enough to find it.

I can do this fine in C# which is what I am using right now, but it would be preferred to have a stored procedure do all of this work.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: @Martin Smith - 
SQL Sever 2008

Comment: @Bob - Does my answer do what you need then?

Comment: Bob L: This might save you some time - [CLR Regex assembly](http://www.mssqlclr.com/?page_id=27).  The download is a deployable sql script; source code download is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Martin Smith - I don't have my laptop which I work on right here but would that solution work even if the test was like this? 'Hello 3 test 315 513 test 321' (where it would only get 315 and 321)?

Comment: @Bob - Yes If the `LIKE` was changed. I'll just make that edit.

Comment: A question like this is often a sign that you need a better data structure design. If you had a related table called test and stored the values in that with an FK to the orginal table, it would be much easier to query. Now if you receive the data like this, I can see using the techniques described to parse it into the correct normalized design. Otherwise, fix your design. 

Also, in databases, it is usually a bad idea to solve a problem by interating.  Databases work best on sets of data and iterating works one row at a time and thus is usually the slowest solution by a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 you can do this

```
WITH testTable AS
(
SELECT 1 AS id_number, N'Hello, test 532. Yay oh and test 111' AS txt UNION ALL
SELECT 2, N'test 932.' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, N'This is a test 315 of stuff test 555.' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, N'haflksdhfal test 311 sadjhfalsd' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, N'Yay.'
)

SELECT id_number,display_term
FROM testTable
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_fts_parser('"' + REPLACE(txt,'"','""') + '"', 1033, 0,0)
WHERE TXT IS NOT NULL and 
  display_term NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' /*Or use LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]' to only get 3 
                                     digit numbers*/
```

Returns

```
id_number   display_term
----------- ------------------------------
1           532
1           111
2           932
3           315
3           555
4           311
```

Comment: I see, I mentioned in a comment above that, the example I gave was the most forward one, where there can be much more inside the text like:

'Hello 31 this is a test ver412 of manliness.' or 'Test-135 yay' or '351 31 test 31 392' which would just be 31.

Comment: Okay this is actually much closer to what I am trying to accomplish however, I think I can work the rest of the criteria out and edit what you've shown (I guess just by chaining OR's to try and cover a variety of possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: @Bob - I think ver412 would trip it up for sure (if the desired result is that the 412 should be extracted?). I think @gbn's should cope with that fine though.

Comment: Hmmm looking at his response I am not sure how it would cope with all the variants of data input. I think this one will suffice, having it be able to wade through wrong input to try and make sense out of it would have been nice but if the input is wrong I think I will just let it stay as wrong. Thanks again for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You are thinking procedurally instead of set based. You can probably write the whole thing as a single query:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (column list)
SELECT (column list)
FROM source_table
WHERE (parse your column) = (some criterion)
```

It is much easier to write, and probably a lot faster too.

If your parsing function is complicated, you can use put it into a user defined function instead of embedding it directly into the query.

Comment: The parsing criteria is a bit too advanced and can contain many different things so the where part would not work but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Bob L: At face value, what you want is a cursor.  But SQL is SET based, and depending on the parsing criteria - more than capable of working within Mark's answer.  I find a very persistent issue with people thinking they're in procedural/OO programming land, and what them struggle to kludge together something that works... while it performs horribly.  Details, even if abstracted, are good for us to help you in your goal.  Maybe you do only need a cursor - I'd like to know more about your needs before I vote for someone's answer.

Comment: I see what you mean. I added some information about what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: +1: Based on the update, assuming CLR is available & OK to be used - best option IMO for the situation.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - As you see from the edit it's a bit more complicated than a 1-1 insert this if somethings true. This is why I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Alright thanks for all the help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Bob L: Your situation is definitely not trivial - I'd be giving out the ol
 stink-eye to whomever gave me that data & requirements...

Comment: @OMG Ponies - hahaha yeah this is getting A LOT more complicated than I was hoping :P I do appreciate all the help though, people are very thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is you always have "Test (number)". It works on SQL Server 2005+

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (id_number int, textcol nvarchar(MAX))

INSERT @Table1 VALUES (1, 'Hello, test 532. Yay oh and test 111')
INSERT @Table1 VALUES (2, 'test 932.')
INSERT @Table1 VALUES (3, 'This is a test 315 of stuff test 555.')
INSERT @Table1 VALUES (4, 'haflksdhfal test 311 sadjhfalsd')
INSERT @Table1 VALUES (5, 'Yay.')


;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP 9999 CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c1.OBJECT_ID) AS varchar(6)) AS TestNum
    FROM sys.columns c1 CROSS JOIN sys.columns c2
)
SELECT id_number, TestNum FROM
    cte
    JOIN
    @Table1 ON PATINDEX('%Test ' + TestNum + '[^0-9]%', textcol) > 0
                    OR textcol LIKE '%Test ' + TestNum
ORDER BY
    id_number
```

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is called a [`CURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190028.aspx) is an article on how to use them.

They are considered bad for performance and difficult to use correctly.

Rethink your problem and restate it so it can be solved in a set based operation.

Look at using [table variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175774.aspx) or [sub queries](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3464481/Using-a-Subquery-in-a-T-SQL-Statement.htm) for your complex condition.

Comment: Oh thanks! I am a bit new to writing more advanced SQL statements other than some relatively intermediate stored procedures.

Comment: Hmm, okay. So you think there is a better way to do this without cursors?

Comment: @Bob L - I urge you to think about solutions that don't require cursors. Temp tables and sub-queries can help with difficult where conditions. Lookup both terms.

Comment: @Oded - The problem is it would be nice to do it as Mark Byers mentioned however the parsing is hard. I want to check through a paragraph stored in the column like:

Hello, test 521, test 431, end.

And insert into a different table the 521 and 431. From what I see about cursors this may be the only solution.

Comment: @Bob L - use a table variable. You can insert ids and data into it, parse and update it and use the results. As @Mark Byers said, you are stuck thinking procedurally instead of set based.

Answer (score 0):

You're after a cursor - see the MSDN docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx).  Note that cursors should be avoided wherever possible - there are very few places that they're appropriate and can result in slow inefficient code - you're usually better off trying a set-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

To do this as you request, with iteration you can do it using a Cursor, using your sample information below is how a cursor is laid-out.  You put your row-by-row process where my comment is.

```
DECLARE @CurrentRecord VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Column
FROM Table 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @CurrentRecord

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       --Your stuff here

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

However, depending on what you are doing, and if this is something that you do on a regular basis.  I would recommend seeing if you can extract the parsing out to a User Defined Function, then you could make it set based, and not use a cursor.  As a cursor should be a "last ditch" effort.