# SQL Query to remove hyperlinks from a column

Tags: sql-server, hyperlink

I have a column dek with the following data

> I like [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) site. The users and answers are good. I also like [site1.com](http://site1.com) and [site2.com](http://site2.com).

I want to retrun the data as follows

> I like Stack Overflow site. The users and answers are good. I also like site1.com and site2.com.

Basically, want to remove all the hyperlinks from the column. Please let me know how to write the SELECT query. I am using SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the hyperlinks actually embedded in your text (e.g., <a href="http://site1.com">site1.com</a>) or is the tool you're using to view the results adding the hyperlink?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383009/tsql-how-do-you-iterate-through-rows-while-parsing-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a function to strip all the HTML from the column contents. Here is a link to a function that will strip out HTML.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/